# How to make reverse relationship query with count in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have related models as defined below. I want to write a query to get all **product** that have **product_options**. I there a way I can achieve this or how to my attempted solution. I have pasted my solution below.

*# Attempted Solution*

```
Product.objects.filter(product_options__count__gt=0)
```

*# Defined models*

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class ProductOption(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name='product_options'
    )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can work with a [**`.annotate()`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) and then [**`.filter(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#filter):

```
from django.db.models import Count

Product.objects.annotate(
    noptions=Count('product_options')
).filter(
    noptions__gt=0
)
```

Since [django-3.2](/questions/tagged/django-3.2), you can also work with [**`.alias(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#alias):

```
from django.db.models import Count

Product.objects.alias(
    noptions=Count('product_options')
).filter(
    noptions__gt=0
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can easily do it by this query

```
Product.objects.filter(product_options__isnull=False)
```

It will send those product that doesn't have product options

Comment: If a `Product` has *multiple* `ProductOption`s, it will retrieve the same `Product` that many times. So likely it is better to work with `.distinct()`.

Comment: My bad, I edited my text in the answer, it will send only those product that doesn't have product options.